How can you adjust the height for leaf nodes in a plotly sunburst?
Using values in a plotly sunburst we can control the width of the leaf nodes. How can we adjust the height?
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Define your custom hierarchy
labels = ["Root", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "AA", "AB", "BA", "AAA", "AAB"]
parents = ["", "Root", "Root", "A", "A", "Root", "Root", "A", "B", "AA", "AA"]
values = [10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 1]

# Create the sunburst chart
fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=labels,
    parents=parents,
    values=values,
))

# Customize the layout (optional)
fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0),
    sunburstcolorway=["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd"],
)

fig.show()


